# Prevent domains from iframing with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I am looking to only allow certain Domains to `iframe` my content and if they aren't on the list they get sent to another page instead this code use to work but no longer does any advice onto why it stopped working and how i would go about fixing it? this is the code that no longer works

```
<script> var ref = document.referrer;  if(ref.indexOf('Domain1.com') < 0 && ref.indexOf('domain2') < 0 && ref.indexOf('domain3') < 0 && ref.indexOf('domain4') < 0 && ref.indexOf('domain5') < 0) { window.location.href = 'https://myhomepage.com'; } </script>
```

so if one of the 5 domains listed embeds the `iframe` it shows the page and any other domain would get the homepage any idea?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

Comment: Any other options for a HTML code? i know PHP has x-Frame but i dont use .php

Comment: `X-Frame-Options` is the old way of doing what the link above suggests, and has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: How would i set it up tho i cant seem to figure it out

Comment: What about `document.location.ancestorOrigins[0]`